# How to adjust time zones in ASP.NET application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

We have ASP.NET application that is hosted on server in +3 time zone. The database is located in +3 time zone as well. The clients can be in other time zones.

The application searches some events by date range. We pick up the dates using 2 Bootstrap date pickers (BeginDate and EndDate). The issue is some events that are before selected BeginDate were returned, which is not correct. For example, if we select on client side BeginDate = 11.02.2015. and EndDate = 11.02.2015. for some time zones the time is shifted in this way:

1. The client is in +3 time zone: @BeginDate='2015-02-11 00:00:00', @EndDate='2015-02-11 00:00:00' (there's no shift because the client and server are in the same time zone)
2. The client is in +6 time zone: @BeginDate='2015-02-10 21:00:00', @EndDate='2015-02-10 21:00:00' (there is a shift of 3 hours because the client is +3 relating to server time zone)
3. The client is in +7 time zone: @BeginDate='2015-02-10 20:00:00', @EndDate='2015-02-10 20:00:00' (there is a shift of 4 hours because the client is +4 relating to server time zone)
4. The client is in +8 time zone: @BeginDate='2015-02-10 19:00:00', @EndDate='2015-02-10 19:00:00' (there is a shift of 5 hours because the client is +5 relating to server time zone)

It's obvious some events from previous day 10.02.2015. will be returned as well.

How to overcome this issue?

Additional information:

It seems the issue is on client side where we have the following code:

```
$scope.actionDatesQuery = {
    actionId: -1,
    limit: 10,
    toJSON: function () {
        return ($scope.actionsQuery.searchText) ? {
            ActionId: this.actionId,
            FromDate: moment().toJSON(),
            ToDate: moment().add('y', 1).toJSON()
        } : {
            ActionId: this.actionId,
            FromDate: ($scope.actionsQuery.fromDate) ? moment($scope.actionsQuery.fromDate).toJSON() : moment().toJSON(),
            ToDate: ($scope.actionsQuery.toDate) ? moment($scope.actionsQuery.toDate).add('d', 1).toJSON() : moment().add('y', 1).toJSON(),
            IsOpenDatesIncluded: $scope.actionsQuery.isOpenDatesIncluded
        };
    }
};
```

After selecting FromDate and ToDate dates, we use them on server side:

```
public IEnumerable<ActionInformation> QueryActionsInformation(ActionsQuery query)
{
    var sql = query.BuildSql();
    using (var cn = ConcertDb.CreateSqlConnection())
    {
        var searchText = string.Empty;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query.SearchText))
            searchText = "%" + DapperUtils.EncodeLikeString(query.SearchText) + "%";

        return cn.Query<ActionInformationDTO>(sql, new
        {
            BeginDate = query.FromDate,
            EndDate = query.ToDate,
            query.CounterAgentId,
            SearchText = searchText,
            query.CityId,
            query.ActionPlaceId,

            query.ActionTypeIDArray,
            query.MaxPrice,
            query.MinPrice
        }).Select(t => (ActionInformation) t);
    }
}
```

As you can see we use moment.js library as well and seems I should change that part on client side, but I'm not sure in which way.

Comment: Do you know the client's *actual time zone*? That won't just be a single UTC offset - it can vary through the year, if they're in a zone that observes DST. There are various ways of detecting a time zone via Javascript. Also, how is the data being stored? If the events each occur in a single time zone, you may want to store the *local* time of the event (and something indicating the time zone). If not, I'd recommend storing them in UTC - try to get rid of *any* dependency on the time zone of the server or the database.

Comment: (And please give some more information about what these events are.)

Comment: Usually you should only deal with UTC on the serv/DB side. So the clients should send/receive UTC dates and display their local datetimes, which is easy to do with Javascript. As long as you keep it strictly like that, there shouldn't be any issues at all. You must make sure that your controllers don't try to transform the received dates *again* (look at DateTime.Kind), that's an annoying behaviour I noticed in a similar project.

Comment: I've added some additional information to the original post. Please, take a look at it.

Comment: @ Jon Skeet: We store the dates of all events as local time of that time zone.

Comment: Of which time zone? The time zone of the event, or the server? And what do you want the search to be for - events in a particular day from the client's perspective, or from the event's perspective?

Comment: We store to database the date and time of the event of the time zone where the event happens. For example, if the event happens in +6 time zone at 11.02.2015. 20:30 (8:30 PM), we store that date and time. We search the events in some range: fromDate - toDate. The events refers to entertainment, such as concerts, theatre, etc.

Comment: Right, so where does the database of the server come in? And do you store the time zone the event is in? What is your search actually meant to search on - local times, or something else? (If I'm in one time zone and the event is in another, what should the search use?) Please use @JonSkeet when you reply so that I am notified of the reply, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a conceptual switch: don't store zoned times in your databases at all, but use UTC instead. This way, it's irrelevant where your servers are physically located.

Then, on the clientside you can use the JavaScript function `Date.getTimezoneOffset()` and pass its value to a hidden field. Upon postback, you can read the value on the server side and react to it in the appropriate way.

Comment: It's too late for such a switch because our database contains a lot of data stored as is.

Comment: This advice may well *not* be appropriate - "use UTC" shouldn't be taken as blanket advice. If an event is in a particular time zone, then that information is useful in itself. For example, if I'm going on a trip and I want to see a play when I'm there, then it's only the *local* date and time of the play that's interesting to me, not the UTC time or the time with respect to my "home" zone. On the other hand, for global events (e.g. a webcast) there's no real "event zone" and UTC is most appropriate. I would certainly agree with not storing things relative to the server zone though.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sure. But aren't you mixing up here the 'meaning' (i.e. the semantics) of a certain local time/event with the technical aspect of abstracting this time for having a generalized storage strategy (i.e. its syntax)?

Comment: @ThomasWeller: I'm suggesting storing the events in their most "obviously useful" semantic form, as that's likely to be easiest to work with. Note that my suggestion *doesn't* lose useful information, whereas yours does - if you're not storing the zone, *just* the UTC value. For some things, a UTC value is really unhelpful, in fact - for recurring events, for example, where the "time of UTC day" may vary because of DST.